# Error while launching turtlebot

Tags: ogre, ros-indigo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am using `roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch` to launch simulation, but I am getting following error :

```
`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Ogre::InvalidParametersException'
  what():  OGRE EXCEPTION(2:InvalidParametersException): Framebuffer incomplete or other FBO status error in GLFrameBufferObject::initialise at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/RenderSystems/GL/src/OgreGLFrameBufferObject.cpp (line 245)
Aborted (core dumped)
[gazebo-1] process has died [pid 5395, exit code 134, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver -e ode /opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_gazebo/worlds/playground.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/siddhesh/.ros/log/d2f7400e-229b-11e6-b846-1008b1cf4251/gazebo-1.log].
log file: /home/siddhesh/.ros/log/d2f7400e-229b-11e6-b846-1008b1cf4251/gazebo-1*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13390/error-while-launching-turtlebot/) by [Siddhesh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2618/siddhesh/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-05-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Take a look at [this](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/29/gzclient-throwing-ogreinvalidparametersexception/) question, it might be an issue with your graphics driver.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Siddhesh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2618/siddhesh/) on 2016-05-26**:
Thanks. I installed graphics drivers and nw its working.